# What's wrong in the php code? Unknown output

Tags: php, api, curl

PHP code file: sms1.php
Located at http://techmentry.com/sms1.php (please visit the link and see the outpur of the below code).

```
<?php
//Variables to POST
$user = "HIDDEN";
$password = "HIDDEN";
$mobiles = "919999999999";
$message = "test";
$sender = "HIDDEN";

//Initialize CURL data to send via POST
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/example.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$user&

password=$password&
mobiles=$mobiles&
message=$message&
sender=$sender"
);

//Execute CURL command and return into variable $result
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//Do stuff
echo "$result"
?>
```

The output I expected is: The above code should have process this URL: URL HIDDEN
and then return a message ID or appropiate error code.

But the output I got is beyond my expection! There are even no error logs. Please help me :)

Comment: `CURLOPT_HEADER` means to include the HTTP headers in the result.

Comment: I deleted that line and it seemed to work. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the code, but you also get the complete response from the server, including HTTP headers.

I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2013 12:24:01 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=60, private, proxy-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 8
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=c9bfcf7ddd3fff9d0a05b34541fbf0a9; expires=Wed, 24-Jul-2013 16:24:01 GMT; path=/

code 105
```

Try to remove this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

Comment: I am new in PHP. Its even a great thing that I coded that myself :P Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: @user2604855 He didn't answer the question though, he just commented on what `CURLOPT_HEADER` does. I think I clearified the problem and answered it with an actual answer. I answered first as well.

Comment: But he answered first and I got to understand :P He will feel bad if I won't accept his answer. I think that doing chat here is not allowed.

Comment: You can't accept an answer in a comment, also I answered one minute before him. Either you have to accept the answer or remove the question as I see it. I will remove my comments when you accept, and so should you.

Comment: @user2604855 You never accepted the answer, you have to click the checkmark next to the answer.