# php- whats the error?

Tags: php, html, api, curl

File Name: sms1.php
Located at: http://techmentry.com/sms1.php

PHP code of sms1.php:

```
<?php
//Variables to POST
$user = "hidden";
$password = "hidden";
$mobiles = "$_POST[phone]";
$message = "$_POST[msg]";
$sender = "$_POST[sender]";

//Initialize CURL data to send via POST to the API
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.hidden/sendhttp.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"user=$user&
password=$password&
mobiles=$mobiles&
message=$message&
sender=$sender"
);

//Execute CURL command and return into variable $result
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//Do stuff
echo "$result";
?>
<br><br><br>
<form name='sms' action='' method='post'>
Phone number<br/><input type='text' name='phone' value='' maxlength=12/>
<br/>
Sender ID (from) <br/><input type='text' name='sender' value='' maxlength=15/>
<br/>
Message : <br/><textarea rows=5 cols=30 name='msg'></textarea>
<br/>
<input type='submit' value='Send'>
</form>
```

Please see the output on http://techmentry.com/sms1.php . It is already displaying an error code (105) (already - because it should show the error code when user click send button). 105 error code means missing 'password' parameter. But I have already stated the password in the code.

Please help :)

Comment: For one thing, your `$mobiles = "$_POST[phone]";`, should read as `$mobiles = $_POST['phone'];` (minus the double-quotes) and use single quotes inside brackets. Do the same for the others, try that.

Comment: @Fred at least tell him the correct syntax... `$mobiles = $_POST['phone'];`

Comment: @Rufinus oopss!!! so true. good catch, will edit, thanks. (I'm on my first coffee), now where's that waitress? WAITRESS?! Double Americano with a shot of Espresso please.

Comment: @user2604855 tell me when you fixed it, so i can use your script to send all my SMS via your script and save some bucks on my end. :)

Comment: l added
    '
in
    $mobiles = $_POST[phone];

Now its
$mobiles = $_POST['phone'];

Now an error:
 Parse error: syntax error,
unexpected
T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE,
expecting T_STRING or
T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in
/home/ash/public_html/sms1.php
on line 6

When I will remove the
    '
then error will also go!

Please help

Comment: The OP has already asked the same/similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833957/whats-wrong-in-the-php-code-unknown-output

Comment: @user2604855 Did you do the same for `$user = "hidden";` `$message = "$_POST[msg]";` etc etc etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking whether the form was submitted, so you're running the cURL code even when displaying the initial form. You need to do:

Change the submit button to:

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send'>
```

and change the PHP code at the top to:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  //Variables to POST
  $user = "hidden";
  $password = "hidden";
  $mobiles = $_POST['phone'];
  $message = $_POST['msg'];
  $sender = $_POST['sender'];

  //Initialize CURL data to send via POST to the API
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.hidden/sendhttp.php");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
              array('user' => $user,
                    'password' => $password,
                    'mobiles' => $mobiles,
                    'message' => $message,
                    'sender' => $sender)
              );

  //Execute CURL command and return into variable $result
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  //Do stuff
  echo "$result";
}
?>
```

The other change I made was to use an array instead of a string as the parameter for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. This avoids having to `urlencode()` all the parameters, which you weren't doing.

And the proper way to assign variables from an associative array is like:

```
$mobiles = $_POST['phone'];
```

The key should be in quotes, the array name itself should not. Your way worked because of the way variable interpolation in strings works, but it's not generally done that way unless you're embedding the variable in a longer string, like:

```
echo "The phone number is $_POST[phone]";
```

Many programmers avoid this syntax entirely, preferring concatenation:

```
echo "The phone number is ". $_POST['phone'];
```

That's a stylistic choice, there's no widespread concensus either way.

Comment: That's exactly what I suggested the OP, however with the `$user = "hidden";` and `$password = "hidden";` you left in there, am under the impression the OP doesn't have much experience, and doubt he/she will follow suit with your example. I for one, think your answer will work, replacing the `"hidden"` values with the proper syntax.

Comment: You also forgot to take out a `"` in `$sender = $_POST['sender']";` ;-)

Comment: I did that. The problem gone and a new arises LOL. When I click send button, its just refreshing the page. It should have return a message ID or an error code :/

Comment: Ahh, your submit button doesn't have `name="submit"`.

Comment: Finally working!! Thank you :) It returned message ID 51efd93046923e8920a6c***

Can you tell how can I replace the message ID to any text when a user click send button?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Lets say this! Visit http://techmentry.com/sms2.php (sms2.php- new one). Enter ur phone no., any sender ID and any text and click SEND. Then it will show you an alphanumeric message ID (example: 54372555446742tgsKAYC38) and you will receive the SMS to your phone no.

So if want want to replace that alphanumeric IDs to any text like "Message sent successfully". How can I?

Comment: Change `echo $result` to `echo "Message sent successfully"`

Comment: But you should probably first check whether `$result` contains an error or a message ID. PHP has string comparison functions that you can use for this.

Comment: I forgotten that! :P Thank you so much for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

"Using PHP variables and newlines within strings often results in problems, could you try the following:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")){
    //this prevents code being executed on page load
    $user = "hidden";
    $password = "hidden";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.hidden/sendhttp.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    //removed newlines and variables in string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"user=".$user.
                                        "&password=".$password.
                                        "&mobiles=". $_POST['phone'].
                                        "&message=". $_POST['msg'] .
                                        "&sender=".$_POST['sender']);

    //Execute CURL command and return into variable $result
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //Do stuff
    echo "$result";
}
?>
<br><br><br>
<form name="sms" action="" method="post">
Phone number<br/><input type="text" name="phone" value="" maxlength="12"/>
<br/>
Sender ID (from) <br/><input type="text" name="sender" value="" maxlength="15"/>
<br/>
Message : <br/><textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="msg"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Qualifier: I'm learning PHP.

Shouldn't you wrap your operations in `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`?

It is processing before you submit anything.

Comment: @Rufinus Glad it wasn't my "edit". You're really "on the ball" this morning! hehehe

Comment: @Fred i'm in the middle of a code review.. few dozen classes of my collegues.. so my "internal syntax parser" is well trained at the moment :D

Comment: @Rufinus You have a "keen eye" ;-)